# C++ Passing param through a class?

Tags: c++, class, param

I'm writing a game; rather than making a complete mess of my code I'd really like to do something like this.

This is how my code is now.

```
bool Verified[18] = { false }; // 18 for (18 clients in game)
```

Than to set that bool I'd obviously do

```
for(int Client;Client<18;Client++)
{
 Verified[Client] = false;
}
```

What I'd like to actually do is this below.

```
static class Clients
{
//Verified size is 18, for (18 clients max in game)
 bool Verified = the value sent by example below to client?

 //some functions i'd like to add later
}
```

What I want to be able to do is this below:

```
Clients[ClientIndex].Verified = false;
Clients[ClientIndex].SomeFunction_Call( < This param same as ClientIndex);
```

I don't know much c++ I know; I fail. But any help would be awesome.

Comment: std::fill_n(Verified, 18, false); fills with false

Comment: @huseyin tugrul buyukisik I don't have the member "Fill_n" and trying to understand what that would do for me :P. I'd like to do it in the format that I provided to clean up and optimize code.

Comment: Can't put `static` on a class in C++

Comment: First off, you should be using `std::array` or vector instead of a raw array. Second, the brace initialization will implicitly fill in the array with false anyway.

Comment: @SergioPotatoNoseAllegretti, Get the idea that writing your own versions of the standard algorithms will clean up and optimize code out of your head right now. `std::fill_n` is in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: I'm trying to stay away from any standard use; it causes problems for a reason.

Comment: Nor do I understand how that would help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no such thing as a `static` class in c++. remove it.

Now after you defined the class (**don't forget ; at the end of the class**)

```
class Client {
public:
   bool var;
   void func (int i);
};
```

You need to create an array (or vector or anything)

```
Client clients[10];
```

then, you can use it like this:

```
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
       clients[i].var = false;
    }
```

Or:

```
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        clients[i].func (i);
    }
```

Comment: I love you, I have not even tried this but I understand it now; thank you soo much.

Comment: An answer confirm will be enough to express your love.

Comment: Aha, sorry; don't use this site much, always need a reminded. That first guy's reply was soo out of whack.  So can I pass a single param in a function within my class from the array index some how?

void verify(int ClientIndex, char status)
clients[1].Unverify("status char"); // (1, "status char")

Comment: What excatly you want to do? use one of the client's inside other client method? i.e. `void func (Client client) { client.var;}` ?

Comment: No, I'd like to know if their's a way to actually pass a variable through the class.

Comment: clients[Index].FunctionCall("param two"); void FunctionCall(int Client, char *text); is there some way that I could actually like "autofll" my first argument with the clients index?

Comment: Rather than calling a function like this. clients[Index].FunctionCall(Index, "char crap"); cause than Index is used twice, why bother if it dosnt need to be.

Comment: Isn't it what we did here? : `for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        clients[i].func (i);
    }` or you looking for? : `for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        clients[i].func (clients[i].var);
    }` because it's possible too.

Comment: wait. No, no, you've got me lost. In otherwords I don't want to have to re-pass the client Index again. "i" is the client Index.

Comment: Here's an example, should clear things up. I'm guessing its not possible. http://i.imgur.com/7v5gTVB.png

Comment: First, you still didn't changed the static class as i told you. To your Q - i dont understand you. In order to active this function you provid the index of the client that you woking on right now. So just do: `clients[i].UnVerify (i , "Whatever string you like");`

Comment: I meant to remove it, yes I know you can do it as you explained. I was asking if it's possible otherwise. Just be "cleaner" you know.

Comment: You can save it in the class i.e. add extra int filed to the class named index but i don't recommand.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I just didn't know how to define it and get the index to store in the class.

Comment: Now I have another problem, I cannot define bool's and INT's to a default value :/ using the "=" op. 
bool cats = false; 
has to be bool cats() { return false; } but than it cant be set, what can I do?